# How do I do an Android Calendar import of recurring events with syncronizing?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

For a students app I've implemented a Calendar import feature. An ICS-File will be downloaded from school website which has several events. All events are single events, not recurring events in the ics-file.
The import works without problems. But when I want to delete all my imported events I sometimes get a message saying that the records cannot be synchronized. What I was thinking of now is:

- Parse ICS-File for all events
- Try to merge events as recurring events
- import the recurring events into calendar

But whatever I do is not working. Either events are marked as recurring but monthly and not weekly as intended. Or keep being imported as single events.

Here's the last code I've tried.

```
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

    event.put("calendar_id", calId);
    event.put("title", title);
    event.put("description", "[HSLU_TAAPP_IMPORTED]");
    event.put("eventLocation", location);
    event.put("eventTimezone", "GMT+1");

    long startTime = startDateTime.getTimeInMillis();
    startDateTime.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    long endTime = startDateTime.getTimeInMillis();
    event.put("dtstart", startTime);
    event.put("rrule", "FREQ=WEEKLY");
    event.put("dtend", endTime);         

    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase()+"events");
    Uri insertedUri = _activity.getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
    return insertedUri;
```

Can anybody give me an example of how to do it right? Or is there another approach intended to get rid of the "cannot synchronize" message?

Comment: Are you running your code on *ics* or *gingerbread/earlier*?

Comment: Code should run on android devices with android 2.3 or higher